# I can't get a row from a database in hibernate with sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load (...)

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a database (in postgres) and I'm working with spring 3 and hibernate 3, the problem is when try to delete or get a row from database, here is the class that I'm using, ohh another thing after the query, a don't have any mistake, the only thing es that class User is null

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDao implements IUserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void SaveUser(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> ListUsers() {
        List<User> users = (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class).list();
        return users;
    }
    public User GetUserById(Integer id) {               
        User user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(User.class, id);
        return user;
    }
}
```

by the way, methods, SaveUser and ListUser work really good.

this is the model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mrbean")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column (name = "id")
private Integer id;

@NotNull (message = "not null")
@NotEmpty (message = "empty")
@Column (name = "user_name", length = 20, nullable = false, unique = true)
private String userName;

@NotNull 
@NotEmpty (message = "empty password")
@Size (min = 7, max = 20, message = "La contraseña debe tener entre 7 y 20 caracteres")
@Column (name = "password", length = 20, nullable = false)
private String password;
```

//with getters and setters

this is what hibernate show in console when 
User user = (User)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(User.class, id) is executed

Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_0_, user0_.password as password0_0_, user0_.user_name as user3_0_0_ from mrbean user0_ where user0_.id=?

Comment: Have you checked that there is a row in the database with the identifier you're passing to your method?

Comment: .... and yes, there is a row in the database with the identifier "id".

Comment: Best to start with the obvious checks :)

Comment: yes of course, you are right, but I was debbuging a lot, and everything seems good. Do you know another way for get a row from database ??

Comment: Please post the source code of `User.class`, its mapping(if there's a separate one)and the text of the query hibernate uses when you call `getCurrentSession().load()`.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and run the query against the database in an SQL tool?

Comment: `@Entity
Table(name = "mrbean")
public class User {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column (name = "id")
 private Integer id;

 @NotNull (message = "not null")
 @NotEmpty (message = "empty")
 @Column (name = "user_name", length = 20, nullable = false, unique = true)
 private String userName;

 @NotNull 
 @NotEmpty (message = "empty password")
 @Size (min = 7, max = 20, message = "La contraseña debe tener entre 7 y 20 caracteres")
 @Column (name = "password", length = 20, nullable = false)
 private String password;`

Comment: sorry, I forgot formatting the code, is on top with first comment, @BorisTreukhov. When execute getCurrentSession().load(User.class, id) in console appear                                             Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_0_, user0_.password as password0_0_, user0_.user_name as user3_0_0_ from mrbean user0_ where user0_.id=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "get" instead of "load" because load() creates a proxy of User (see Hibernate ref doc )
so i would try : User user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);

Comment: thanks a lot, it works now I can get a use from database but when I execute getCurrentSession().delete(user) doesn't work. Only work with HQL, ...mmm those method of getCurrentSession(), I think is better not to used, what do you think, any recomendation??? Or I start to learn HQL. Thanks everyone for your comments really helpfull

Comment: just give us your code for the delete, and i will try to help you out.There is nothing wrong with your getCurrentSession(). Most of the time you would factorize it ina private method like :  private Session getSession() {
  return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
 }